# use pdfs as source for textures in Xcode 6 spritekit level editor

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

In iOS apps we're now able to use pdfs and in the compilation step appropriate sized .pngs will generated (including @2x and @3x sized and named files).  Is it possible to use the same format for generating the right correct sized textures for use in sprite kit?

The spritekit level editor does "see" the images in the files in the preview area at the bottom right of the editor but unlike standard .pngs which can be just dragged across to the level editor, the pdfs won't go.

Comment: You mean Xcode generates PNG files from a PDF when building (compiling) the code? Do you have a link or reference for that feature? I have never heard of that. In Sprite Kit you can only use image (png) files, SK can not load or use PDF files in any shape or form.

Comment: Yep, that's right, its a very helpful feature that saves exporting lots of different sized images from Illustrator - I use it both my apps on the App Store: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found that it is not possible to use PDFs as the source for SpriteKit textures.